# Date conversion using UDF in cosmos db

Tags: javascript, date, user-defined-functions, date-conversion

my date is in string and like this **13-Jul-2020**
how can I convert it into cosmos db date format **"2020-10-07T00:00:00.000Z"** using **User Defined Function** or **javascript**

Comment: Please do some research. There are tons of related questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split() to split the date into its component parts, then use Date.UTC to convert to unix time. NB: I'm assuming your date 13-Jul-2020 is in UTC. If it's in local time, we'd use new Date(year, month, day) instead.

```js
// Use this if your date string refers to UTC time
function parseUTCTimestamp(s) {
    const monthIndexes = { 
        jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4, jun:5,
        jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11 
    };
    const [day, month, year] = s.toLowerCase().split('-');
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, monthIndexes[month], day)).toISOString();
}

console.log("UTC:", parseUTCTimestamp("13-Jul-2020"));
console.log("UTC:", parseUTCTimestamp("17-aug-2020"));

// Use this if your date string refers to local time
function parseLocalTimestamp(s) {
    const monthIndexes = { 
        jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4, jun:5,
        jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11 
    };
    const [day, month, year] = s.toLowerCase().split('-');
    return new Date(year, monthIndexes[month], day).toISOString();
}

console.log("Local:", parseLocalTimestamp("13-Jul-2020"));
console.log("Local:", parseLocalTimestamp("17-aug-2020"));
```